# i want to write seo friendly url from blog links,i have tried but not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog_details/([0-9]) blog_details.php?p_id=$1[NC,L]

#Rewrite for blog_details.php?p_id=1&post_title=post_title
RewriteRule ^blog_details/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ blog_details.php?p_id=$1&post_title=$2[NC,L]
```

this is my link what i want to convert
`http://localhost/cedervilla/blog_details.php?p_id=12&post_title=post%20title%201`

Comment: This question has been answered hundreds of times. Please do not be lazy and search via Google!

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog_details/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ blog_details.php?p_id=$1&post_title=$2 [L]
```